# A Linux shell script corrupts Intel graphics display data buffer and then restores it periodically

Tags: graphics, buffer, display

I'm new to shell scripting and would like to learn how to write a shell script that corrupts the Intel display graphics buffer for a few frames for 1 second, then turns off for 10 seconds and repeats the procedure 20 times before exiting.

Can I obtain guidance and a sample code for the shell script I want to run as a bash script?

Thank you very much.